# How do I get the results from argmax of [0., 1e-8]?

Tags: floating-point, overflow, argmax, underflow, float32

When I ran below code, I got x=1, y=0

```
a = np.array([0., 1e-8]).astype('float32') 
x = a.argmax()
y = (a+1).argmax()
```

I already know floating point expression. But, I don't know why I can get x=1, y=0.
I think that overflow or underflow can be related to the results.
Please help to explain!

Comment: `1+1e-8 == 1` when calculated with `float32`, so the 0th element is also a maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `1e-8` is converted to `float32`, the result is the nearest number representable in `float32`, which is 9.99999993922529029077850282192230224609375e-09, which is about 1.34•2<sup>−27</sup>.

So, in real-number arithmetic, the sum of 1 and 9.99999993922529029077850282192230224609375e-09 is about 1 + 1.34•2<sup>−27</sup>. The two numbers representable in `float32` that are closest to that are 1 and 1+2<sup>−23</sup>. Of those two, 1 is closer to 1 + 1.34•2<sup>−27</sup>, so `float32` addition produces 1 as a result. Thus, the elements of `a+1` are 1 and 1. Both are tied candidates for the maximum, and `argmax` returns the index of the first one.

Comment: "Thus, the elements of a+1 are 1 and 1." needs re-wording to be clear.